# Marking some, but not all, elements as bold

Tags: javascript, html, css

Within my project I have a single panel which contains a series of individual hyperlinks, all of which I have injected dynamically from the database.

My client wants me to make some of the hyperlinks bold, and some remain normal. Could anyone explain how I might make some of them bold?

I've tried the following things, but this changes *all* of the hyperlinks to bold.

I'm open to making the change at the java source file level or wherever else is necessary.

```
font-weight: bold; /* css */
style="bold";
```

Comment: #footer .footer_content a{ color:#ccc; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; } .Mam i am using this one but it changes all the texts into bold.I want some them should be bold,i tried with your code it also changes all the texts into bold.can you pls...

Comment: Which elements do you want to be in bold? Based on what criteria? Is it random, or is there a particular situation under which given elements should be bold? What's your HTML? What have you tried?

Comment: I have one panel as i said in my post.In that panel I have some categories,and under each category i have some subcategories.Now what my requirement is i want make all the Categories should be bold.SubCategories as usual noraml.That's it...

Comment: And yet you're still not showing any html that shows your page structure. Help us to help you, give us something to work with.

Comment: Right now it seems to come ....just wait i will intimate you after success..

Comment: sorry it's not working,it displays all the texts as bold,can you say one more way.....

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
.boldclass{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

add this css class to the hyperlink element to make it bold

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbkYY/)

---

**Edit:**

Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c63xX/)

In this fiddle. I've applied `red`color to all anchor tags.

If you want to give bold to only some anchor tags, you can use the `class` attribute of anchor tag and specify your css class. Inorder to distinguish i've give the `boldclass` color as `green`.

Ex: `<a href="#" class="boldclass">hello</a> //This will take the css specified in .boldclass`.`

Hope this clarifies you

---

**Add Styles to XML**

Here is a more detailed explanation of how to apply styles to your xml file.

[Applying Styles to XML](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html)

Try this link also. It is from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: #footer .footer_content a{ color:#ccc; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; }    I am using this code but it changes all the texts into bold,but my requirement is i want to make bold some texts only in my webpage.

Comment: Did you not even read the answer? Put in Karthik's CSS rule and apply `class="boldclass"` to those links you want to make bold.

Comment: I have tried in that what you said,but still it shows all the texts as bold,but my requirement is some of them should be bold...thanks bala

Comment: #footer .footer_content a{ color:#ccc; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; } --> This line will set all anchor tags. If you use `a{}` it applies to all anchor tags

Comment: @balanagaraju put your entire code in this post. So, that we can help you better

Comment: Right now it seems to come with your code....just wait i will intimate you after success...

Comment: sorry ...it's not working...with the bove even removing 'a' {} ,can you say one more way.....

Comment: I want to apply bold to specific one let us suppose "goods",can you write code in ui.xml  to make this specific one bold (or) in css by using 
 
#footer .footer_content a{ color:#ccc; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; }